# How to call redis PUBLISH from Oracle 10g database?

Tags: oracle, redis

I have a channel in Redis and I need to publish a message in it in Oracle 10g database PL/SQL procedure. I have found ORedis which doesn't support publish, though.

What would be a good approach?